# How to get the text content of hidden element with changing values

Tags: javascript, selenium, selenium-webdriver, hidden

Here the element I want to test for

```
        <div id="console-modal" class="tab-item hide-item green-outline">
          <p id="message-box"></p>
          <button id="console-modal-button" class="white-button btn-md">close</button>
        </div>
```

when some action occur, I am adding a message to the `<p>` and setting the display of the `<div>` to block.
In my test with selenium I expect to get the message that is present present in the updated `<p>` element. But it is returning an empty string.

This is the code that perform the action to update the `<p>` element

```
  it('should fill the login form and submit', () => {
    driver.findElement(By.id('username')).sendKeys('johnd');
    driver.findElement(By.id('passwd')).sendKeys('12345');
    return driver.findElement(By.id('inline-signin-button')).click();
  });
```

This is the test I am executing to test the content of the `#message-box`. In place of `innerHTML` I have also tried `textContent`. Also, when I add some text to the `<p>` element, the test is able to get the content, but it is not getting the updated content after the action completes and the box is displayed.

```
it('should find the auth error modal and close', () => {
   driver.wait(until.elementLocated(By.id('console-modal')));
   driver.findElement(By.id('message-box')).isDisplayed();
   return expect(driver.findElement(By.id('message-box')).getAttribute('innerHTML')).to.eventually.equal('authentication fail! check your username and password')
driver.findElement(By.id('console-modal-button')).click();
 });
```

I expect that the returned valued to be the updated content of the `<p>` element, but it appears it is keeping the content as of when the element is still hidden. Is there a way I could get the updated text content when it element is displayed. Or is there a way I could delay the execution until the element is displayed before testing it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the below wait until.

```
var pElement = driver.wait(until.elementLocated(By.xpath("//div[@id='console-modal'][not(contains(@class,'hide-'))]/p[@id='message-box']")));
```

we are waiting until the `div` class name does not have `hide`, to make sure the block is displayed (which will make sure the p text update)